# Analogs for PostgreSQL "interval" in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a piece of code I have in PostgreSQL, however I need to use it in T-SQL. How can write this 'interval '7d' part when joining two tables? Are there any 'interval' analogs in t-sql?

```
  LEFT JOIN UserActivity ua
    ON ua.UserID = ur.UserID
      AND ur.RegistrationDate = ua.UserLoginDate - interval '7d'
```

Comment: look up `datediff` function.

Comment: 7 days before x is `dateadd(day, -7, x)`

Comment: No, there are no analogs, you just have wait 7 days to run the next query.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql syntax is `DateDiff(day, [first date], [lastDate])`  It returns the number of date boundaries between the two dates.  or use `DateAdd(day, [number days to add], [startDate])`

Comment: DATEADD works great. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use:

```
LEFT JOIN
UserActivity ua
ON ua.UserID = ur.UserID AND
   ur.RegistrationDate = DATEADD(day, -7, ua.UserLoginDate)
```

Note:  In both databases, this assumes that the columns are dates with no time components.

There is (currently) no functionality in SQL Server that exactly matches the `interval` functionality in Postgres and other databases.  However, the base functions of `dateadd()`, `datediff()`, and `datepart()` are usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace that last line with something like this:

```
AND DATEDIFF(d, ur.RegistrationDate, ua.UserLoginDate) = 7
```